# The radius of convergence of a square-summability sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^2<\infty$.
How to prove that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq1$?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/148510).  It is better to ask a question that provides context and evidence of your own work.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$1).\ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n|^{\frac{2}{n}}\le 1$ since otherwise the series doesn't converge.

$2).\ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n|^{\frac{2}{n}}=\underset{k\to \infty}\lim\sup_{n\ge k}|a_n|^{\frac{2}{n}}.\ $ So if $k$ is large enough, $\sup_{n\ge k}|a_n|^{\frac{2}{n}}< 1+\epsilon.$

$3).\ |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\sqrt {|a_n|^{\frac{2}{n}}}.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}=r>1$. By definition of $\limsup$ (the supremum of the set of all subsequential limits), choose $\epsilon>0$ so that $r>r-\epsilon>1$. Then $r-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound for the set of subsequential limits so there exists a convergent subsequence with $r-\epsilon<|a_{n_k}|^{1/n_k}$ for all $k$ sufficiently large. What's the problem with this (square the inequality to use $|a_n|^2$? What do you know about the tail of convergent sequences?